# Can't activate experimental Particle Nodes/ Simulation Window

Tags: experimental-features, particle-nodes

Was the experimental Particle Nodes Feature removed in 2.91.0 Beta? (Nov 8, 00:34:11)
I’m Trying to access it via Preferences > Experimental but there is nothing there but “Debugging”-Features. Interface > Developer Tools is checked.
Did search for it excessively, but couldn’t find anything about that problem.
Also I wasn’t able to find a branch.
And I got the same problem in 2.9 and 2.92 Alpha.

Maybe it’s a bug in my install? Factory Reset doesn’t change anything, sadly.

Comment: I think the experimental features are only included in the experimental 'daily' builds, not the official releases. You'll probably need to download from https://builder.blender.org/download/branches/ for those features.

Comment: That was it! Found it with your link as "experimental-build branch". Thank you RichSedman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experimental features are only included in the experimental 'daily' builds, not the official releases. You'll probably need to download from https://builder.blender.org/download/branches/ for those features.